NOAA data in BigQuery not being updated?
This is a duplicate of the question here, but it's a current issue. It seems that this dataset is no longer being updated. Is it a bug or intentional on google's part?
Here's a quick check for recent data:
SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_global_forecast_system.NOAA_GFS0P25` 
 WHERE DATE(creation_time) >= "2024-06-18"


I am seeing this too. :(

Since you said this is a duplicate question ... and in the original, Google responded with "You can always email public-data-help@google.com for assistance" ... have you done that?

Does this answer your question? NOAA Forecast data in BigQuery no longer being updated?

I've created a support ticket—thanks.

When I run the below bq command:
bq show  bigquery-public-data:noaa_global_forecast_system.NOAA_GFS0P25
It seems the dataset is last updated on 17 Jun.

When I change your query  to SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bigquery-public-data.noaa_global_forecast_system.NOAA_GFS0P25 WHERE DATE(creation_time) >= "2024-06-16" I am getting the count as  “6233766”.
From the above two executions it seems like the dataset is updating but not up to date. Based on my experience this is usual  but if you want up to date results you can raise a ticket to request for an update in public dataset in this issue tracker.

Added: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/348148931
